# Selective routing with OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

Hi I am connecting to my private server through an OpenVPN using a .ovpn configuration. However when I am connected to the VPN I need to access some servers in my Local Network with the ip range 10.*.*.*  How can I selectivley not route the LAN traffic while routing all other traffic through openvpn 
I get the following log when connecting

```
Mon Oct 13 05:20:16 2014 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Mon Oct 13 05:20:16 2014 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 172.27.232.12/21 broadcast 172.27.239.255
Mon Oct 13 05:20:21 2014 ROUTE remote_host is NOT LOCAL
Mon Oct 13 05:20:21 2014 /sbin/ip route add 107.170.153.39/32 via 10.52.128.1
Mon Oct 13 05:20:21 2014 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 172.27.232.1
Mon Oct 13 05:20:21 2014 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 172.27.232.1
Mon Oct 13 05:20:21 2014 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Comment: did you try to run a route command locally to send all 10.* traffic to your gateway yet?

Comment: What is the command i am not much familliar with linux routing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in a openvpn config. So you have to do it post connect but something like

```
 ip route add 10.0.1.0/24  dev eth0
```

That assumes your local lan is on 10.0.1.0/24 and your connection to that lan is eth0

Comment: actually all ips from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255 belongs to my LAN so if i use 10.0.0.0/2 is it correct ??

Comment: no it would be 10.0.0.0/8

Comment: ip route add 10.0.0.0/8  dev eth0 worked ill edit your answer

Comment: ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 10.52.128.1 dev eth0 worked finally

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: I realized I misread your question. Mike's answer works for you but I'm not sure it will be persistent across reboot.**

In your openvpn configuration file you could do something like:

Server config

```
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"
```

OR you could add this in your client config

```
route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
```

Comment: I am having a .ovpn config where should i add this ?

Comment: If you control the openvpn server you would add it there, server.conf for example.
Otherwise add "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0" to your .ovpn without quotes.

Comment: Mikes answer gave an error i improvised it . if i am spcifying the gateway how can i use it in your command

Comment: Well you can't really. You need to manually add a route from your computer to your local servers. If you control the openvpn server though, you could stop redirecting all traffic via VPN and only allow traffic to your server behind the VPN. The rest goes through your normal router and you would have access to your local servers.